How to read raw input in a linux terminal application
I'm trying to read raw key presses in a linux console application. First try was using crossterm enable_raw_mode()
use std::io::Read;

use crossterm::terminal::enable_raw_mode;

fn main() {
    enable_raw_mode().expect("Could not enable raw mode");

    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    for data in stdin.bytes() {
        let data = data.expect("Could not read char");

        print!("Got char: {:#x}\r\n", data);
    }
}

While this generally works, it has two drawbacks:

I would like to know which button a user pressed regardless of their current keyboard mapping
Dead keys are not reported using this method, until a second key is pressed as well

Especially the second point is problematic for my use case.
I have read here that you can change the way keypresses are reported to the terminal using ioctl. This was my second attempt, using that approach:
use std::io::Read;

use nix::ioctl_write_int_bad;

ioctl_write_int_bad!(setkbdmode, 0x4B45);

fn main() {
    unsafe { setkbdmode(0, 0).expect("Here goes") };

    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    for data in stdin.bytes() {
        let data = data.expect("Could not read char");

        println!("Got char: {:#x}", data);
    }
}

However this fails with the following error:
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:8:31:
Could not set kbd mode: ENOTTY
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

It seems that this only works on virtual terminals, not terminal emulators.
Is there a way to get the data I need in a linux console application running in a terminal emulator? Specifially:

Get all key presses, even on dead keys
Preferably as scan codes, not by translated keys


>Is there a way to get the data I need in a linux console application running in a terminal emulator? Most likely there is no way. You can read raw key events from underluying display server (Xorg, Wayland compisitor), or from device, e.g. with libinput, libevdev or directly from /dev/input/* character device.
